# for loop to add new values to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

So I am trying to add a new column to my dataframe that contains the side/radius given the shape and area of each row.

My original dataset looks like this:

`df`:

```
    shape     color   area  
0   square    yellow  9409.0    
1   circle    yellow  4071.5    
2   triangle  blue    2028.0    
3   square    blue    3025.0
```

But when I coded it like this:

```
df['side'] = 0
for x in df['shape']:
    if x == 'square':
        df['side'] = np.rint(np.sqrt(df['area'])).astype(int)
    elif x == 'triangle':
        df['side'] = np.rint(np.sqrt((4 * df['area'])/np.sqrt(3))).astype(int)
    elif x == 'circle':
        df['side'] = np.rint(np.sqrt(df['area']/np.pi)).astype(int)
```

I got:

```
    shape     color   area    size
0   square    yellow  9409.0  55
1   circle    yellow  4071.5  36    
2   triangle  blue    2028.0  25    
3   square    blue    3025.0  31
```

It looks like the loop is adding the `elif x == 'circle'` clause to the side column for every row.

Comment: Your assignments are assigning to all the rows, not the current row of the `for` loop.

Comment: So each time through the loop, you're updating all the sides, and the final values will be based on the last value of `df['shape']`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a good use case for `numpy.select`, where you select values depending on which shape it is:

```
import numpy as np
df['side'] = np.select([df['shape']=='square', 
                        df['shape']=='circle', 
                        df['shape']=='triangle'], 
                       [np.rint(np.sqrt(df['area'])), 
                        np.rint(np.sqrt(df['area']/np.pi)), 
                        np.rint(np.sqrt((4 * df['area'])/np.sqrt(3)))], 
                       np.nan).astype(int)
```

It could be written more concisely by creating a mapping from shape to multiplier; then use pandas vectorized operations:

```
mapping = {'square': 1, 'circle': 1 / np.pi, 'triangle': 4 / np.sqrt(3)}
df['side'] = df['shape'].map(mapping).mul(df['area']).pow(1/2).round(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
      shape   color    area  side
0    square  yellow  9409.0    97
1    circle  yellow  4071.5    36
2  triangle    blue  2028.0    68
3    square    blue  3025.0    55
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you were assigning to the columns. you can iterate over each row and edit it as you iterate over it using `iterrows ()` method on dataFrame.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['shape'] == 'square':
        df.at[i,'side'] = np.rint(np.sqrt(row['area'])).astype(int)
    elif row['shape'] == 'triangle':
        df.at[i,'side'] = np.rint(np.sqrt((4 * row['area'])/np.sqrt(3))).astype(int)
    elif row['shape'] == 'circle':
        df.at[i,'side'] = np.rint(np.sqrt(row['area']/np.pi)).astype(int)
```

note the assignment is to cell of a column on row at index `i`.

also, suggestion by @enke above will work just fine.